# Calling an asynchronous javascript function on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Can anyone please advise:

I have written a client side webpage which has a Websocket connection to a server side node app. All works fine.

When a certain message is sent through the websocket form the client I get the server to respond (again through the Websocket connection) with some text and I display that on the client side when the reposnse is received. All works fine.

Now, what if I want to make the function on the server an asynchronous one, which waits 4 seconds before returning the string. I can't get that to work, the string is returning as "[object Promise]".

So, the original synchronous code on the server,which is executed in reposnse to the client calling and is working is:

```
Chatterer.prototype.HandleASCIIMessage = function(szMessage, ws)
{
    ws.send("BANG");
}
```

Now I have replaced this by with:

```
Chatterer.prototype.HandleASCIIMessage = function (szMessage, ws)
{
    var sz = this.Test();
    ws.send(sz);
}
```

Where Test is:

```
Chatterer.prototype.Test = function()
{
    return this.ShowResult();
}
```

And the remainder of the code is:

```
Chatterer.prototype.ShowResult = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.GetAsync();

    return result;
}

Chatterer.prototype.GetAsync = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.AsyncFunc();

    return result;
}

Chatterer.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function ()
{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("BANG");
        }, 4000);
    });
}
```

I am trying to not have the ws.send(sz) line called until the 4 seconds is up.

Thanks,
Mitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Chatterer.prototype.ShowResult = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.GetAsync();

    return result;
}
```

The above function returns a promise (an async function returns a promise). This means that the following returns a promise too:

```js
Chatterer.prototype.Test = function()
{
    return this.ShowResult();
}
```

You could make the above `async` as well to make it more obvious, yet it's not technically needed.

This means that here:

```js
Chatterer.prototype.HandleASCIIMessage = function (szMessage, ws)
{
    var sz = this.Test();
    ws.send(sz);
}
```

`sz` is a promise, so either make `HandleASCIIMessage` `async` and `var sz = await this.Test();`, or use the vanilla `Promise` API with `this.Test().then(sz => ws.send(sz))`.